# Making skype like token field for adding users to a chat

Tags: cocoa, nstokenfield

In Mac, in skype when we add users to an existing chat, by clicking '+' button on top, a beak like window appears carrying a token field like control. When an user types some name in it and a match is found then a list appears carrying user icon , status icon and his/her name. Also the width of dynamic list is same as beak window.

Can any one suggest some way to create similar control?

Thanks in advance,

Miraaj

Answer (score 2):

[`NSTokenField`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTokenField_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: yes I know it is NSTokenField but default token field is different than that! In default no image appears in dynamic list. Also the width of dynamic list is smaller.... can you give me some clue to bring desired look and feel!

Answer (score 1):

The control for the list would be [NSTableView](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).